# Changing Cakephp project name gives error

Tags: php, cakephp, forum

I am using cakeforum (http://cakeforum.inservio.ba/) code and have changed it a little bit according to my needs but when I try to change its root name i.e. from cakeforum to hippo (or something else), its stops working i.e. it stops showing any output.

Is there any configuration that I have left out?

Answer (score 0):

It should be working though. check webroot's index.php if there's some root name defined.

what version of cake is it?